# custom URL Routing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to create custom routing using asp.net and HTTP-handlers. How to do it. Please suggest me some links. I don't want to do it using MVC routing way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many articles

https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx